# Can a function's return type depend on an input argument's value?

Tags: typescript

Given an interface, I'd like to create a function that picks a property of that interface, which property can be specified as an input argument.

This is the closest I've come:

```js
interface Source {
    a?: string;
    b?: boolean;
    c?: number;
}

function getPropertyFromFirstExisting(
    arr: Source[],
    property: keyof Source
): Source[keyof Source] {
    return arr.map(el => el[property]).filter(prop => !!prop)[0];
}

const sourceArr = [
    { a: 'asdf', c: 12 },
    { b: true }
];

interface Target {
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: number;
}

const result: Target = {
    // the property result.a should only be string type
    a: getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr, 'a'),
    // the property result.b should only be boolean type
    b: getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr, 'b'),
    // the property result.c should only be number type
    c: getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr, 'c')
};
```

In this case the `getPropertyFromFirstExisting` has a return type of `string | boolean | number`, but with a good solution it should be only one of those, depending on the `property` input parameter. Is this possible?

[Here's a link to the example in the TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Source%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20arr%3A%20Source%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property%3A%20keyof%20Source%0D%0A)%3A%20Source%5Bkeyof%20Source%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arr.map(el%20%3D%3E%20el%5Bproperty%5D).filter(prop%20%3D%3E%20!!prop)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20sourceArr%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20'asdf'%2C%20c%3A%2012%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20b%3A%20true%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Target%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%3A%20Target%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20property%20result.a%20should%20only%20be%20string%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr%2C%20'a')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20property%20result.b%20should%20only%20be%20boolean%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr%2C%20'b')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20property%20result.c%20should%20only%20be%20number%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr%2C%20'c')%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close but `Source[keyof Source]` will give you a union of all possible values in `Source` you need an extra type parameter to capture the actual key that is passed in and use that to type query into `Source`:

```
function getPropertyFromFirstExisting<K extends keyof Source>(
    arr: Source[],
    property: K
): Source[K] {
    return arr.map(el => el[property]).filter(prop => !!prop)[0];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Source%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Source%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20arr%3A%20Source%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property%3A%20K%0D%0A)%3A%20Source%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arr.map(el%20%3D%3E%20el%5Bproperty%5D).filter(prop%20%3D%3E%20!!prop)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20sourceArr%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20'asdf'%2C%20c%3A%2012%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20b%3A%20true%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Target%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%3A%20Target%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20property%20result.a%20should%20only%20be%20string%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr%2C%20'a')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20property%20result.b%20should%20only%20be%20boolean%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr%2C%20'b')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20property%20result.c%20should%20only%20be%20number%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20getPropertyFromFirstExisting(sourceArr%2C%20'c')%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)